# Remove only right indent when using displayquote and csquotes

Tags: indentation, quoting, csquotes

**Problem:**

Removing right indent when using `displayquote` in `csquotes`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{displayquote}
"If you want to design intervention X [for the purpose/function Y in context Z], then you are best advised to give that intervention the characteristics A, B, and C [substantive emphasis], and to do that via procedures K, L, and M [procedural emphasis], because of arguments P, Q, and R."
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Desired output:**

No right indentation for the quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `csquotes` just uses the standard `quote` environment internally as the basis for this. So you can just redefine that to remove the right indent:

```
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{}%
 \item\relax}
{\endlist}
```